# Align entire page contents puts form slightly off centre

Tags: html, css

```css
.formholder {
width: inherit;
}

.formposition
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


input[type=text], select {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 2vh 4vh;
    margin: 1vh;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 0.5vh #ffffff;
    border-radius: 1vh;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: solid 0.5vh #ffffff;
}

.formposition {
position: absolute;
width: auto;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

input[type=text], select {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 2vh 4vh;
    margin: 1vh;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 0.5vh #ffffff;
    border-radius: 1vh;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: solid 0.5vh #ffffff;
}

input[type=submit] {
width: 100%;
    padding: 2vh 4vh;
    margin: 1vh;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 1vh;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: solid 0.5vh #ffffff;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
input[type=submit] {
width: 100%;
    padding: 2vh 4vh;
    margin: 1vh;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 1vh;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: solid 0.5vh #ffffff;
}
}

form {
    width: auto;
    margin-left: 0vh;
    margin-right: 0vh;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="formholder">
<div class="formposition">
<form action="responses.php" method="post">
<input type="text" placeholder= "Test Field" name="TestField" required><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

The DIVs work to centre but the form isn't fully centred within itself.

[image: Alignment Highlighted]
The button and inputs should be fully centred on the page but they don't touch the left of the DIV and they overflow on the right including the border.

The entirety of the contents will sit in the middle of the page. Due to the form elements being off centre there's slightly more space on the left and it's visibly obvious that they're not centred.

A fix or pointer would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is becuse of the left and right margin on the `input[type=submit]`. Change it to `margin: 1vh 0` to solve this since you want it to go 100% width.

The real width of your input is 100% + 1vh (right margin) + 1vh (left margin). Margin does not get calculated into width.

```css
.formholder {
width: inherit;
}

.formposition
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


input[type=text], select {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 2vh 4vh;
    margin: 1vh 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 0.5vh #ffffff;
    border-radius: 1vh;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: solid 0.5vh #ffffff;
}

.formposition {
position: absolute;
width: auto;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

input[type=text], select {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 2vh 4vh;
    margin: 1vh 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 0.5vh #ffffff;
    border-radius: 1vh;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: solid 0.5vh #ffffff;
}

input[type=submit] {
width: 100%;
    padding: 2vh 4vh;
    margin: 1vh 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 1vh;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: solid 0.5vh #ffffff;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
input[type=submit] {
width: 100%;
    padding: 2vh 4vh;
    margin: 1vh 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 1vh;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: solid 0.5vh #ffffff;
}
}

form {
    width: auto;
    margin-left: 0vh;
    margin-right: 0vh;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="formholder">
<div class="formposition">
<form action="responses.php" method="post">
<input type="text" placeholder= "Test Field" name="TestField" required><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, Thank You! I'd tried defining it twice, I forgot that was an option :)

Comment: no problem. Also, if you did want to keep the margins you could use the css `calc` function to remove the margin from the width calculation. So you would change the width to be: `width: calc(100% - 2vh)` then you could keep `margin: 1vh`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the left & right margins of the inputs are pushing the input outside of the containing form/divs. Try using "margin: 1vh 0;" on the inputs instead of "margin: 1vh;".